# Always prompt for Boot Device on Startup?

Tags: macos, windows, macbook-pro, startup

I have a MacBook where I have to dual boot Windows and OS X. When I hold the Option Key on startup, I get the nice "Select Boot Device" screen.

Is there a way to permanently enable this, so that I don't have to remember to hold option every time I restart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to install a boot loader such as [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/).

This will present you with a menu similar to the following when you start up your computer:

[image]

Comment: That seemed like a mighty large stone to kill a very small bird, but it works fine :)

Comment: Since rEFIt is no longer under active development, consider using rEFInd (http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) - it is a fork of rEFIt.

Answer (score 2):

On Intel-based Macs, this supposedly works (unverified):

```
sudo nvram manufacturing-enter-picker=true
```

Note that this reportedly is **not** supported on ARM-based Macs.

Comment: Good find! There are some other nvram options for booting to recovery etc documented here : https://mrmacintosh.com/boot-to-internet-recovery-recovery-partition-or-diagnostics-from-macos/